# Security Risk issue in search bar of interactive Report / ORACLE APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am working on a project using Oracle Apex 22.1, and I have a problem in the search bar of interactive report: when I put a script in the search input (like: `<script>alert('hello apex')</script>`), it executes the code instead of escaping the characters as you see in these screenshots:

[image]

[image]

I looked at the docs of apex, but there is no attribute of interactive Report that enable escaping special characters.

Comment: Report it to Oracle as a bug.

Comment: apex.oracle.com runs the latest version, 23.2.4 - can't reproduce it there.

Comment: cannot be reproduced even on 18.x

Comment: I already test it in the cloud (23 version) and it does not reproduce .but I have it in the 22 version and I can't upgrade to 23 right now

Answer (score 0):

I love to see someone finding these bugs, hahahaha. Good one.
This issue has been fixed in later version. I suggest upgrading your APEX so get the updated Interactive Report